# Buffering Audio Streams in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, audio-streaming, memorystream, circular-buffer, binarywriter

I am working on a Internet radio streaming application for Windows Phone. I am researching the best-practices and different implementations. I am using the following code to read the stream:

```
private MemoryStream bufferStream;
private Stream stream;

...
...
...

byte[] data = new byte[2048];

int read;

while (true)
{
    read = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(bufferStream);
    bw.Write(data);
    bw.Flush();
}
```

I am not sure whether this is an efficient way. Also, I saw an circular buffer implementation. What is the most-efficient way to stream the music without any "hiccups", "artifacts" and interruptions?

Answer (score 0):

I found [phonesm project on codeplex](https://phonesm.codeplex.com/) that provides great examples and functionality for implementing internet audio streaming.

Have a look over here too:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/smooth-streaming-on-windows-phone-7/

Hope this helps!